# What character could be made with these radicals?

Tags: characters

Chinese Characters Decomposition

丿  piě slash
十  shí ten
一  yī one
丨  gǔn line

Comment: I guess it's maybe 仕

Comment: 仕 shì ‘official’ includes radical 亻 rén 'man'. In this poll radical 亻 rén 'man' is not included. Do you possibly have another idea? :)

Comment: 亻  does consist of 丿 and 丨, so it looks like 仕 could be a valid answer.

Comment: I have nothing but accept your point of view. Thank you very much. Nevertherless, radicals 丿 piě slash 十 shí ten 一 yī one 丨 gǔn line can form some more simple Chinese characters, can't they?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a 卉

> huì
>   各种供观赏的草的总称
>   花～|奇花异～。
>   Which means general term for a variety of 
>   ornamental grasses.

Comment: Perfect finding - 卉 huì ‘grass’! Any other options?

Comment: It is not correct, according to [stroke order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_order), Chinese characters are written top to bottom, not bottom to top : [http://www.zhihuishan.com/data/gif/1747.gif](http://www.zhihuishan.com/data/gif/1747.gif)

Comment: I know it,but It doesn't restrict the stroke order.

Answer (score 1):

1. 丿一丨一 ： Radical [牛 (牜, ⺧)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_93)
2. 丿一丨一丨：Many characters start with this set of strokes.

[image]

Comment: Accepted. Can you offer any a-three-stroke Chinese character?

Comment: Radicals, ordered by stroke count : [https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=radicals&cdqraddm=1](https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=radicals&cdqraddm=1)

Comment: @NicolayShinkin, the following link is about how the accept the answer on stackexchange : [http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: These radicals :丿 piě slash 十 shí ten 一 yī one 丨 gǔn line form a a-three-stroke Chinese character.